# Direct sum of subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

Define the subspaces $U_1$ and $U_2$ of $\mathbb R^3$ by
$U_1= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3: x+y+z=0\}$  and $U_2= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3: x=0\}$.

Prove:

a) $U_1 + U_2 = \mathbb R^3$

b) $\mathbb R^3 \neq U_1\oplus U_2$. where $\oplus$ indicates the direct sum of vector spaces.

For part a) I have the following: Suppose $U_1$ and $U_2$ are subspaces of $\mathbb R^3$ defined by $U_1= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3: x+y+z=0\}$  and $U_2= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3: x=0\}$. Take $\mathbf u_1\in U_1, u_1 = (x, -x, 0)$ and $\mathbf u_2\in U_2, u_2 = (0, x+y, z)$, then $ \mathbf u_1 + \mathbf u_2 \in U_1 +U_2$,
$$\mathbf u_1 + \mathbf u_2 = (x, -x, 0) + (0, x+y, z) 
= (x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^3  \text{ for all }    x,y,z \in \mathbb R^3$$
Is this enough for part a)?

Now for part b) I am confused about what we want to show. Is there a counterexample? Also, I have a hard time fully understanding the direct sum.

Answer (score 3):

In part b), for this to be a direct sum we would need
$U_{1} 
\cap U_{2} = \{0\}$
, which is clearly not the case ($(0,-1,1) \in U_{1} \cap U_{2}$ for example).

In general, if $V$ is a vector space and $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$ are subspaces of $V$, then $V = U_{1} \oplus U_{2}$ if and only if $U_{1} + U_{2} = V$ and $U_{1} \cap U_{2} =\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you! I thought about it but wasn't entirely sure. From the intersection, we can obtain infinitely many solutions in the form (0, -t, t) that do not equal a zero vector.

Answer (score 1):

Part a) is no entirely correct. You should start from an arbitrary element $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3$ and then show that it can be written as the sum of an element of $U_1$ with an element of $U_2$. The way that you have found to do that ($(x,y,z)=(x,-x,0)+(0,x+y,z)$) is indeed correct.

But it's not the only solution. You also have, for instance, that$$(x,y,z)=(x,-x,z)+(0,x+y,0).$$So, for instance, $(0,0,1)$ can be written in more than one way as the sum of an element of $U_1$ with an element of $U_2$. And therefore you do not have a direct sum. If you had a direct sum, then an arbitrary element of $\Bbb R^3$ could be written in one *and only one* way as the sum of an element of $U_1$ with an element of $U_2$.

Comment: Thank you! I see that for part a). Is this the case when I need to show that they are subsets of each other or it is enough to show that for an arbitrary element (x,y,z) there exist two vectors s.t. ....

Comment: You only have to show that any element of the whole space can be written as the sum of an element of the first subspace with an element of the second one.